# Prevent ion-content to reduce size on <select> focus

Tags: ionic-framework

I've noticed that when every time an input/select tag is being focused inside a modal, it dynamically changes the height of the ion-content (eg. sets the height to 240px and adds an overflow visible).

Here's a screenshot:

**If select tag is focused**

[image]

**If select tag is not focused**

[image]

Now the question is how to prevent Ionic from changing the ion-content height?
Because currently everytime I focused on a select tag it makes the layout ugly.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I also ran into the same problem it is to do with ionics Scroll which resizes on focus of an input i noticed the same thing happening with the ion-scroll directive so i just added a fixed height to ion-content.

```
ion-content{
    height: 80% !important;
    overflow: hidden !important;
}
```

Now it will always maintain a height of 80% and keep the overflow hidden when scrolling you may want to add a custom class or id to ion-content rather than using the directive name though. Thought that would just be easier as an example for my problem i set a class of "box-full" so it will only be used when i need it on certain ionic scroll elements. I hope this solution helps you and anyone else who had this same issue.

Comment: maybe overflow: hidden !important; prevents scrolling. So in my case I just needed only the first line: height: xx% !important;